# What does += mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “+=” (plus equals) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638502/what-does-plus-equals-mean)

What is the point of `sum += square` below? What does it mean?

```
sum = 0
[1, 2, 3, 4].each do |value|
  square = value * value
  sum += square
end
puts sum
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sum = sum + square
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
sum=4 
sum += 5  #9
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read up ["Pragmatic Programmer's Guide to Ruby"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356085).  Very nice explanation of Ruby concepts for beginners.