# What does "+=" (plus equals) mean?

Tags: ruby, operators

I am doing some ruby exercises and it said I need to go back and rewrite the script with `+=` shorthand notations.

This exercise deals primarily with learning new methods. The problem is, I have no idea what `+=` means when I tried to look it up online.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "+=" (plus equals) mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022524/what-does-plus-equals-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 66):

`+=` is a shorthand operator.

```
someVar += otherVar
```

is the same as

```
someVar = someVar + otherVar
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help I appreciate the speedy answer.

Comment: And `someVar = someVar + otherVar` is the same as `someVar = someVar.+(otherVar)`. Feel free to write your own class and implement `+` on it, and you, too, can have the `+=` magic!

Comment: Note that you (probably) need to return `self` in your `+` function to make `+=` work as expected.

Comment: I've got something a little more advanced that I wanted to [ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101146/why-does-this-expression-cause-a-floating-point-error) Can people explain the difference between `a*=b` and `a=a*b` (see link for more details) I had assumed they were the same although this doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: @MikeH-R - It looks like you already have the answer - order of operations.

Answer (score 15):

Expressions with *binary operators* of the form:

```
x = x op y
```

Can be written as:

```
x op= y
```

For instance:

```
x += y   # x = x + y
x /= y   # x = x / y
x ||= y  # x = x || y (but see disclaimer)
```

However, be warned that `||=` and `&&=` can behave slightly ... different (most evident when used in conjunction with a hash indexer). Plenty of SO questions about this oddity though.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Not an ruby expert but I would think that it either appends to an existing String or increments an numeric variable?

Answer (score 1):

You should look for a good book about Ruby, e.g. http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9

The first 150 pages cover most of the basic things about Ruby.

```
str = "I want to learn Ruby"

i = 0
str.split.each do |word|
  i += 1
end

puts "#{i} words in the sentence \"#{str}\""

  => 5 words in the sentence "I want to learn Ruby"
```