# What does "+=" (plus equals) mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm going through a Ruby tutorial and I can't grasp the += statement. Google isn't helping, "Ruby +=" only searches for "Ruby".

Help is appreciated.

Sample:

```
num = -10
num += -1 if num < 0
puts num   
#=> -11
```

Comment: `a += 1` is the same as `a = a + 1`
`+=` is just a short form.

Comment: I _hate_ post-conditions, code should be read like (English) text, left-to-right and downwards. Damn you to perdition, Perl :-)

Comment: (Try a tutorial; in any case, the keyword is "operator", of which there is a finite set and the rules are well-covered.)

Comment: It should be closed as a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638502/what-does-plus-equals-mean

Comment: Try using SymbolHound http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%2B%3D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
num += -1
```

is an equivalent of

```
num = num + -1
```

or, for this example

```
num = num - 1
```

which, in turn, can be written as

```
num -= 1
```

Comment: Also note that almost any operator can be combined with `=`: `&&=`, `||=`, `&=`, `|=`, `*=`, `/=`, and so on. See "assignment" in [this table from the Pickaxe](http://phrogz.net/programmingruby/language.html#table_18.4).

Answer (score 0):

It does two things at once.

(1) It adds + 1 to num
(2) Assigns back the result to num

Its a shortcut for:

`num = num + 1`

Answer (score 0):

The segment `a += b` is just the short form for `a = a + b`. So your statement:

```
num += -1 if num < 0
```

will simply subtract one (by adding `-1` which is ... quaint, that's probably as polite as I can be) from `num` if it is already negative (if `num < 0`)..